# Php generate first password building the system

Tags: php, passwords

I'm new to php programming.  I'm working on a small site for a friend where he will upload his works. 
I have implemented a simple admin section, password protected, where he can manage the site's content. 
The password is hashed using "password_hash()" and stored in a sqlite db. 
Actually for testing purpose I created manually the user's credentials using sql, with a password created from terminal. 
When the site will be online, is there a way (or best practice) to let my friend create his own password without using a temporary password?

It could be a strange question, but it seems to me so complex to create the first password through terminal and save it with sql... There isn't a better way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when u will release the project, there should be no password set for the admin account, and at first authentication, your friend should be asked to set his password ? 
If that's what your project is supposed to do, I would do this way :

1 : build a auth form, with mail and password fields

2 : on Auth attempt :

2.A : if password is not provided and mail-related account in DB has no password yet, 
display a new field where the user will set his password. Use this data to generate hashed password (password_hash($_POST['password']) and save it into DB.

2.B : if password is provided, do the check between mail and password (basic auth behavior)

3 : Auth the user